# Proper Way to Pass Props to React Class By Calling as a Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code which passes renderTabs to a shared  component.  In the shared search component it calls back the passed in function (that being my renderTabs).  I don't know how to properly set SearchResults, I am not doing it right.

I will also note that originally renderTabs was a function inside the container that had all the logic but I moved that out to a new  component so that it could be more easily maintained after abstracted.  Before this renderTabs() in Container.js looked like this:

**Web Project - consumes and uses Search.js from shared react project**

**Prior to me changing it in Container.js:**

```
renderTabs() {
   ...bunch of logic

      return (
        <li key={paneId}>
          {item}
        </li>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>{tabs}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Container.js** I've now abstracted the stuff above into a new container called `<SearchTabs />`.

```
  renderTabs() {
    const { selectedTab, selectedFilter, isDropdownOpen } = this.props;
    return (<SearchTabs
      fetchSearch={this.props.fetchSearch}
      isDropdownOpen={isDropdownOpen}
      onFilterClick={this.onFilterClick}
      selectedFilter={selectedFilter}
      selectedTab={selectedTab}
      setTab={setTab}
      resetNextPage={this.props.resetNextPage}
    />);
  }
 // We now pass the renderTabs callback to Search.js so that Search.js can call it (hence render the tabs) when it's ready to
 render() {
    return (
      <Search
        renderTabs={this.renderTabs}
      />
    );
```

**Shared React Project consumed by Web Project**

**Search.js** (our shared component)

So now I'm in the shared component and I want to call the renderTabs so that it renders .  I can't get this working.  **When I run the site I only see literal text outputted as text 'tabs', not a react component so I'm not calling this right.**

```
render() {
    const {
      renderSearchResults,
      renderTabs,
      //....rest of the props are here
    } = this.props;

    const { response: searchResults } = this.state;
    const tabs = renderTabs();
    // const tabs = React.cloneElement(renderTabs, { searchResults });

    const icon = hideIcon ? null : (
      <div className={theme.searchIcon}>
        <Icon icon="search" />
      </div>
    );
    const searchResultsTags = renderSearchResults({
      userInput,
      searchResults,
      loading,
    });
    return (<div>{tabs}</div>);
  }
```

**I also tried this but it didn't render the .  I would have expected react to have called renderTabs but...???:**

```
render() {
    const {
      renderSearchResults,
      renderTabs,
      //....rest of the props are here
    } = this.props;

    const { response: searchResults } = this.state;
    //const tabs = renderTabs({ searchResults });
    // const tabs = React.cloneElement(renderTabs, { searchResults });

    const icon = hideIcon ? null : (
      <div className={theme.searchIcon}>
        <Icon icon="search" />
      </div>
    );
    const searchResultsTags = renderSearchResults({
      userInput,
      searchResults,
      loading,
    });
    return ({tabs});
  }
```

**Update**

It's definitely coming through as a function in Search.js

[image]

**Update 2**

But trying this, this also didn't work:

```
    const tabs = () => renderTabs();

 <div> { tabs() } </div>
// also tried  <div> { tabs } </div>
```

And here's what it renders in the bundle.js, still treats tabs as text:

[image]

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow the flow of the program. You seem to want to pass `searchResults` to your renderTabs function, but that function doesn't take any arguments in the code you've shown here. It would probably help to see more of your code, if you could (for example) post a link to JSFiddle. I have a [base fiddle, setup for React](https://jsfiddle.net/jonahe/c8sw3t2a/),  that you can use as a base if you want. Press "Fork" and you can start pasting your code (deleting the old one is fine).

Comment: yea you can ignore the SearchResults really I just want to know how to render the passed in function.  the passed in function being my <SearchTabs /> really

Comment: basically it's the job of Search.js to take in my <SearchTabs /> and invoke it thus render it inside it's render()  because it manages some stuff first then eventually calls back my renderTabs() to render it.  my renderTabs() lives in another project that's consuming this shared Search.js

Comment: I've updated my post a bit, added a comment and the fact that Container.js lives in another project that consumes Search.js

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it may be related to your `this` context. Make sure you are binding `renderTabs` to your `Container` component in the `constructor` of `Container` like so:

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.renderTabs = this.renderTabs.bind(this);
}
```

If you've done that, you may be running into the ol' infinite loop thing. Since `renderTabs()` is rendering `SearchTabs`, it is calling the `render()` method on `SearchTabs`. I'm guessing some `prop` or piece of `state` on `SearchTabs` is getting changed, resulting in infinite re-renders. Try wrapping your callback in an arrow function like this:

`const tabs = () => { this.renderTabs({ searchResults }) };`

and then call the `tabs` function to get your JSX. Those would be my best bets. It also looks like you're passing an argument to `renderTabs` but you don't define that argument or what `renderTabs` should do with that argument. Best of luck!

Comment: nice idea, added the bind, but it's not rendering my tabs at all still

Comment: forget about the argument being passed, I'm going to remove it above

Comment: so it renders text 'tabs' not a react component when Search.js tries to call it in its render().  In Search.js I have {tabs} but that's not generating a <SearchTabs />.  So I'm just not doing something right.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like this:

Shared component:

```
render() {
 const a = this.props.testFunc ? this.props.testFunc() : null;
 console.log("Shared:", a);
 ...
}
```

Parent component:

```
testFunc() {
    const a = "asd";
    console.log("Parent:", a);
    return a;
}

render() {
    return (<Shared testFunc={this.testFunc} />);
}
```

Console Output is like that:

```
Parent: asd
Shared: asd
Parent: asd
Shared: asd
```

But if I change the **testFunc** to this:

```
testFunc() {
    const a = this.props";
    console.log("Parent:", a);
    return a;
}
```

Output is like that:

```
Parent: undefined
Shared: undefined
Parent: undefined
Shared: undefined
```

I assume you want to access **this.props** inside the renderTabs function.
Try this solution

Parent Component

```
testFunc = (props) => {
    const a = props;
    console.log("Parent:", a);
    return a;
  }
render() {
    return (<Shared testFunc={() => this.testFunc(this.props)} />);
}
```

For your example:

```
renderTabs(props) {
    const { selectedTab, selectedFilter, isDropdownOpen } = props;
    return (<SearchTabs
      fetchSearch={this.props.fetchSearch}
      isDropdownOpen={isDropdownOpen}
      onFilterClick={this.onFilterClick}
      selectedFilter={selectedFilter}
      selectedTab={selectedTab}
      setTab={setTab}
      resetNextPage={this.props.resetNextPage}
    />);
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <Search
        renderTabs={() => this.renderTabs(this.props)}
      />
    );
```

Comment: I don't care so much about being able to work with passed props that Search.js wants to pass, I just can't get the dang thing to render period from Search.js

Comment: So,
`this.renderTabs = this.renderTabs.bind(this);
 ` should work.
Or `renderTabs={() => this.renderTabs()}` is an option too.

Comment: I added `this.renderTabs = this.renderTabs.bind(this)` already in Container.js

Comment: I am not sure if you can define jsx as a const inside a func. Could you try `return (<div>{renderTabs()}</div>);` instead of `return (<div>{tabs}</div>);`

Comment: about to throw my laptop against wall brb :)

Comment: All I am trying to do is render what the func returns which is a <HeaderSearch />.  Search.js should be able to just invoke that function and it renders what that func returns which is a <HeaderSearch \> simple as that